# Обособление оборота со словом "будто" в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять сравнительный оборот в этом предложении: "Будто бешеная, верещала ее дочь"?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь возможны **оба варианта** (структура предложения позволяет, но при этом интонация разная). Также при выборе надо учитывать контекст:

**(1) Будто бЕшеная //верещала ее дОчь.**

**(2) Будто бЕшеная, верещАла ее дОчь.**

**Препозиция** оборота обычно способствует отсутствию обособления
Сравнить: Ее дочь верещала, **будто бешеная.**

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:

1) если на первый план выступает **значение обстоятельства образа действия:** **Как зарницы в небе** они запылали, **как огненный дождь с неба** упали;

Пример:

Лошади... **рванулись и помчались, будто бешеные**. [И. И. Лажечников. Беленькие, черненькие и серенькие (1856)]

Comment: Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* — это не сравнительный оборот с союзом *будто*. Розенталь их четко разделил.

Comment: Союз КАК - неспециализированный, общего характера, он может выражать достоверное и недостоверное (воображаемое) сравнение. Союзы БУДТО, СЛОВНО - недостоверные союзы. Таким образом, разница грамматическая, какое отношение это имеет к пунктуации?

Comment: Розенталь разделяет правила обособления для оборотов с как и оборотов с будто.

Answer (score 0):

**Будто бешеная, верещала ее дочь.**

Сравнительный оборот, присоединяющийся союзом *будто*, обособляется, и его расположение на это не влияет.

Comment: Это оборот? И он действительно сравнительный?

Comment: @shampar, По-моему, да. Если у Вас есть другое мнение, не прячте его за вопросами.

Comment: :) Изменением порядка слов смысл "бешенства" можно сделать буквальным (вместо сравнительного). Тогда запятая исчезает. _Из конуры Жучки слышался зловещий звук. Будто бешеная дочь её верещала._